# R tm prevent lower case conversion when using DocumentTermMatrix

Tags: r, tm

When I use DocumentTermMatrix on my corpus, it lowercases the words. I'd like to preserve the camel case. How do I do it?

```
as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(c("Hello", "World")))))
```

I'd like the column names to be Hello and World instead of hello and world.

Comment: Does that mean you want to treat the words "Hello" and "hello" as distinct? Because that's what preserving case implies.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want to treat Hello and hello as separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following hack:

```
words <- c("Hello", "World")
tdm <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(words)))))
names(tdm) <- sort(words) # need to sort alphabetically
tdm
#  Hello World
#1     1     0
#2     0     1
```

Cleaner way to do the same:

```
words <- c("Hello", "World")
tdm <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(factor(words))), 
                                                         control=list(tolower=FALSE))))
tdm
#  Hello World
#1     1     0
#2     0     1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that. The above example was just to provide a simple example. I need to be able to do it by either passing some sort of a parameter to DocumentTermMatirx.

Comment: Updated the code as per your requirement, i think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`capitalize` function in `library(Hmisc)` does the job for me as a beginner.

```
library(Hmisc)

terms <- as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(c("Hello", "World")))))

colnames(terms) <- capitalize(colnames(terms))

terms

    Terms
Docs Hello World
  1     1     0
  2     0     1
```